# String pointer on heap vs stack for called function

Tags: c

I've written the following basic C program to print a string and learn a bit about memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * get_string() {
    char * s = "OK";
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char * string = get_string();
    printf("String: %s\n", string);     
    return 0;
}
```

And this works and prints:

> String: OK

My question is why does this work? For example, in `get_string()` isn't the variable `s` stored to the stack and not the heap, and why doesn't that variable "disappear" when it is passed back to the main function?  How can something like this be done without calling `malloc` in the called function, `get_string()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's stored in a global data section.

If you replaced that line with:

```
char s[] = "OK";
```

*then* your program would not work.

To be specific, this string is stored in the data of the program file and the function is actually returning a pointer to the location where that data is stored.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the pointer `s` with the string it points at.  `s` is indeed stored on the stack, but it points at a static constant string (in the program's read-only data section) `"OK"`.  When you `return s;` the pointer is copied to the caller and stored into `main`'s stack frame in `string`.  The string it points at remains the static string in the data section.